# why session push in laravel store my value in new array with zero index

Tags: php, laravel-4

my first code line is

```
Session::put('step_1', array('security' => 'yes'));
```

2nd is

```
    $vat=10;
    \Session::push('step_1.vat',$vat);
```

my current output:

```
Array
(
    [security] => yes
    [vat] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
        )

)
```

**My Desired Output:**

```
Array
(
    [security] => yes
    [vat] => 10
)
```

hot to achieve my desired output, please suggest, thanks.

Comment: is $vat an array? what happens if you do Session::push('step_1.vat',$vat[0])?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use

```
Session::put('step_1.security', 'yes'));
$vat=10;
Session::put('step_1.vat', $vat);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have been into the mess. What I did was, getting the session to a variable, forgetting it, adding more data and adding to the session variable again. This is a simple workaround in your case,

```
$session = Session::get("step_1");
Session::forget("step_1");
$session['vat'] = 10;
Session::put('step_1', $session);
```

if you dig into the laravel source, Session::push,

```
/**
 * Push a value onto a session array.
 *
 * @param  string  $key
 * @param  mixed   $value
 * @return void
 */
public function push($key, $value)
{
    $array = $this->get($key, array());

    $array[] = $value;

    $this->put($key, $array);
}
```

This is the reason for adding an index.

Comment: please check what my desired output is

Comment: no, Array ( [0] => Array ( [security] => yes [vat] => 10 ) ), please check it put all in first zero index

Answer (score 0):

i found this way very easy and convenient:

```
$step_1 = \Session::get('step_1');
$step_1['vat'] = $vat;
\Session::put('step_1', $step_1);
```